# How to calculate the integral $\int_a^\infty \int_0^{2 \pi}\rho\, \mathrm e^{i k \rho \cos(\phi-\theta)} \sin\phi\, \mathrm d \rho\, \mathrm d\phi$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, fourier-transform, trigonometric-integrals

How can I calculate below integral? Is there any analytical solution for below integral?

$$\int_a^\infty \int_0^{2 \pi}\frac{\rho}{(a^2+\rho^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}}\, \mathrm e^{i k \rho \cos(\phi-\theta)} \sin\phi\, \mathrm d \rho\, \mathrm d\phi$$

Comment: An integral sign with two differentials!

Comment: integral on angle is from 0 tot 2pi. I taught it is obvious @MyGlasses

Comment: Do you know the answer? @AccidentalFourierTransform

Comment: there was a mistake in the question. I have edited it @PierpaoloVivo

Comment: Are you sure?! thre is sin(\phi) in integrand @PierpaoloVivo